# How to customize ProgressDialog in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to customize the ProgressDialog, need to change message color, animated image and dialog-background color. Can anybody help me on this. I am new to android.

How to change the animated image displayed inside the ProgressDialog, where I need to made changes for this?  I saw that such APIs are not there in ProgressDialog class.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: how did you change dialog background color and add customized button to progress dialog ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is custom dialog example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ . 
And here is progress bar example which you can add to custom dialog: http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/progress-bar-tutorial-for-android/